# Como definir melhor a API minima para um projeto?

Tags: android

Comecei um projeto e tive muitos problemas por que escolhi a versao 2.3 como base, agora estou trabalhando em um outro aplicativo que vai ter que ter: conexão com banco de dados online, e salvar edicao em fotos, no caso só um texto escrito na foto, acho que é o canvas que terei de usar, qual a versão minima que devo usar? Fazendo um bom aplicativo, bom design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João, acho que pra definir os requirements de qualquer aplicação você precisa ter em mente duas coisas:

1. Qual o público alvo do seu projeto. Eles tem acesso a quais requerimentos mínimos?
2. Quais requisitos mínimos são necessários para que se atinja o objetivo da sua aplicação?

Obviamente, você deve definir o 2 pensando no seu público alvo. Defina quem você vai atingir, depois defina os requisitos que você pode ter na sua aplicação e voilá, você terá os requerimentos mínimos necessários para o seu sistema. 
Não adianta usar o máximo de tecnologia se seu público-alvo não tiver ela disponível, como também não adianta usar uma tecnologia que ficou para trás e não conseguir desenvolver aplicativos melhores. É uma balança.

Comment: Entendi, preciso que meu aplicativo seja usado pelo maior número de pessoas possíveis, então acho que vou ter que me adaptar e usar a versão 2.3 como base, acho que dá pra usar, pois na 2.2 eu conseguia usar snapchat, e eu preciso de câmera, e tal. E o snapchat tinha tudo que vou precisar, então eu acho que dá sim.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas um complemento...

A Google disponibiliza um [gráfico](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net) dos dispositivos android, isso é muito interessante pois os dados ajudam como argumento para convencer o cliente ou você mesmo. Como você pode ver, aproximadamente 85,8 dos dispositivos rodam android a partir da plataforma 15, eu considero uma boa opção para a API mínima.